# User input is bugged | 4trthgr appears. Where does it come from and why is it there?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Okay so I am writing something with appscript and everything works fine, except that on one line that is to replaced with user input (##variable## --> Userinput) a "**4trthgr" comes out of nowhere.**

Variables:

[image]

Bug:

[image]

Code:

```
js
function Prompt() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`
    <style>
      .modal-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 175vh;
        width: 350px;
        background-color: #EDEADE;
      }
      img {
        display: flex;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        position: relative;
        top: 200px;
        left: 100px;
        
      }
      .form-container {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        max-width: 400px;
        width: 350px;
      }

      .form-field {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .form-field label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #333333;
      }

      .form-field input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-size: 14px;
        outline: none;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 300px;
      }

      .form-field input:focus {
        border-color: #4caf50;
      }

      .submit-button {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
      }

      .submit-button button {
        background-color: #4caf50;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: none;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
    </style>
    <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/905241590509998100/1128354543189622834/AA_-_MAIN_NO_BG_NO_BLUR.png">

    <div class="modal-container">
      <div class="form-container">
        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="discordID">Candidates Discord ID:</label>
          <input type="text" id="discordID" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="robloxName">Candidates Roblox Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="robloxName" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="discordName">Candidates Discord Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="discordName" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="score">Candidates Score:</label>
          <input type="text" id="score" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="inviligatorName">Inviligator's Discord Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="inviligatorName" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="inviligatorID">Inviligator's Discord ID:</label>
          <input type="text" id="inviligatorID" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
          <label for="modCommandName">Moderation Command's Name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="modCommandName" />
        </div>
        <div class="submit-button">
          <button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script> 
      function submitForm() {
        var formElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var response = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++) {
          var element = formElements[i];
          response[element.id] = element.value;
        }

        google.script.run.promptFormResponse(response);
        google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>
  `).setWidth(400).setHeight(600);

  ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "Please Enter Details");
}

function promptFormResponse(response) {
  var CandidateID = response.discordID;
  var CandidateRobloxName = response.robloxName;
  var CandidateDiscordName = response.discordName;
  var CandidateScore = response.score;
  var TotalScore = 26;
  var CompareScore = parseInt(CandidateScore);
  var Grade;

  if (CompareScore === 26) {
    Grade = "S";
  } else if (CompareScore <= 25 && CompareScore >= 23) {
    Grade = "A";
  } else if (CompareScore <= 23 && CompareScore >= 22) {
    Grade = "B";
  } else if (CompareScore <= 21 && CompareScore >= 19) {
    Grade = "C";
  } else if (CompareScore <= 18) {
    Grade = "Failed";
  }

  var InviligatorDiscordName = response.inviligatorName;
  var InviligatorDiscordID = response.inviligatorID;
  var ModCommandName = response.modCommandName;
  var today = new Date();
  var formattedToday = Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");

  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById("16aHBanoZcYb5o9CMxx5bur3GyXuIOvVUZANAkoYqz5Q").makeCopy().getId();
  var docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId);
  docFile.setName(CandidateDiscordName + "_" + formattedToday + "_Moderator Certificate");

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
  var body = doc.getBody();

  var searchReplaceText = {
    "##CDiscordID##": CandidateID,
    "##date##": formattedToday,
    "##CRoName##": CandidateRobloxName,
    "##CDcName##": CandidateDiscordName,
    "##Score##": CompareScore,
    "##Total##": TotalScore,
    "##Outcome##": Grade,
    "##InName##": InviligatorDiscordName,
    "##InDcID##": InviligatorDiscordID,
    "##MCName##": ModCommandName,
    "##InSignature##": InviligatorDiscordName,
    "##MCSignature##": ModCommandName
  };

  for (var searchValue in searchReplaceText) {
    var replaceValue = searchReplaceText[searchValue];
    if (replaceValue !== undefined) {
      body.replaceText(searchValue, replaceValue.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

I expected it to change from ##InName## to the user input. It did not replace it but put a 4trthgr inside of it.

****more clearness cant be given since its all I have****

Comment: About `I expected it to change from ##InName## to the user input. It did not replace it but put a 4trthgr inside of it.`, when I saw your showing script when a value is inputted to `<input type="text" id="inviligatorName" />`, `var InviligatorDiscordName = response.inviligatorName` has a value. So, I cannot understand your current situation. In this case, I think that it is required to know the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation. So, can you provide the detailed flow for it?

Comment: starting at the for (var)

Comment: Remember to reduce your code to [mcve] form. Most of what you're showing is [entirely unrelated](/help/how-to-ask) to the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from `starting at the for (var)`, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans since I dont know what part creates the error, it is crucial to include everything in order to prevent sending a snippet of a functional code. Thank you for your response though. It is all of the code I use, so IT IS related

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans code works connected if you didnt know. If I removed specific parts none of it would work. This is SO, so to help with code problems. if you want to make any constructive contributions please tell me, otherwise the conversation is over from my side. You were not helpful at all